# Infinite Multidimensional Array where one value is overwritten

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I'm experimenting with arrays for an explanation and I came across this weirdness. I did this in the console:

```
    var x = ['Paul Irish', 'Alex Sexton', 'Nicholas Zakas'],
    y = x,
    z = y;

y[1] = x[0]; // we're trying to switch Alex with Paul
z[2] = y[0]; // we're trying to switch Nick with Paul
x[2] = x; // whoops a typo
```

And created infinite arrays within every internal key 2.

```
// ["Paul Irish", "Paul Irish", Array[3]]: // infinite arrays
```

Then I assigned another name to one of the MD values:

```
x[2][2][2] = 'Jenn Schiffer';
```

But didn't expect this:

```
x[2][2][2] // undefined
x[2][2][1] // undefined
x[2][2][0] // n
x[2][2]    // n
x[2][1]    // e
x[2][0]    // J
x[2]       // Jenn Schiffer
x[1]       // Paul Irish
x[0]       // Paul Irish
```

I can not explain these results, (tested on the latest Chrome & FF).
How did the assigned string become an array dispersed into other keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did

```
x[2] = x;
```

`x` has actually become,

```
[ 'Paul Irish', 'Paul Irish', [Circular] ]
```

it means the second element of `x` is `x` only and then when you did

```
x[2][2][2] = 'Jenn Schiffer';
```

`x[2]` refers `x` only. So, `x[2][2]` again refers `x` only. So, the expression, `x[2][2][2]` is the same as `x[2]`. You can understand this like this

```
x[2][2][2] => (x[2])[2][2] => (x)[2][2] => (x[2])[2] => x[2]
```

You are basically removing the circular reference by assigning a string with `x[2][2][2] = 'Jenn Schiffer';`. At this point, `x` is

```
[ 'Paul Irish', 'Paul Irish', 'Jenn Schiffer' ]
```

Now, when you do

```
x[2][2][2]
```

`x[2]` is `'Jenn Schiffer'`, `x[2][2]` is `n` and `'n'[2]` is `undefined`.